# Single Page | Chrome exstension

Tags: chrome-extension

Возникли проблемы с `js` в `Chrome exstension`.

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "*://vk.com/groups*" ],
      "js": [ "js/vk/groups.js" ]
    }
  ],
```

Если я открываю `https://vk.com/groups` напрямую, скрипт работает.
Но, например, мой текущий URL `https://vk.com`, и я нажимаю кнопку «Группы», которая должна редеректить меня на `https://vk.com/groups` и в этом случае ничего не происходит.

Chrome, похоже, не регает переходы на `Single Page`

Я пытался сделать вот так:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.url === "https://vk.com/groups")
        // Call groups.js
});
```

Но не знаю, как вызвать `groups.js`.

Приехал [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64756809/strange-behavior-of-chrome-exstension).